C++ build automation tool with online repository
Существуют ли для экосистемы C++ системы сборки проектов, позволяющие подгружать необходимые зависимости из некоторых онлайн репозиториев, как это делают Maven и Gradle? Можно ли использовать Maven и Gradle только для указания зависимостей в проекте C++, по аналогии с Make?
Насколько я помню, make работает только с локальными библиотеками.
Т.е. к примеру подгрузить необходимые исходники с телом функций (не file.h). По выражению include <file.h> или по указанию в файле make/pom.xml? Как вообще при создании проекта на C++ подгружают библиотеки, которых нет на локальной машине?
Каждый компилятор имеет свой путь, где он ищет либы. Обычно новые либы (Boost?) добавляют в эти пути? Или локально в проект?

https://cmake.org/cmake/help/latest/module/FetchContent.html типа такого?

Для С++ нет адекватных систем сборок проектов. И онлайн репозиториев тоже нет. А те, что есть, обычно либо не содержат нужных библиотек, либо не могут быть использованы, так как их содержимое не собрано совместимым с проектом образом. Единственная рабочая схема - писать свою систему сборки, самостоятельно подтягивая и собирая сторонние проекты. А инструмент, который бы мог по названию заголовочного файла подтянуть нужный исходник - это что-то типа грааля.

"Обычно новые либы (Boost?) добавляют в эти пути? Или локально в проект?" - обычно добавляют в компилятор новые пути. ЗЫ лучи ненависти в сторону gradle

https://conan.io/ - можно создать свой репозиторий, есть двоичные пакеты / https://vcpkg.io/en/packages - сборка только из исходников, для изменения пакетов нужно форкать. Как по мне, vcpkg проще в подключении, а conan более гибкий.

Пакетных менеджеров куча разных. Conan и vcpkg - кросс-платформенные (хотя последний больше под msvc заточен). На каждом дистрибутиве линукса можно использовать их пакеты. Для mingw есть msys2. Для CMake есть есть на выбор FetchContent и CPM... Как ни странно, я скорее согласен с user7860670, что часто проще своими скриптами билдить зависимости, чем разбираться что там наворотили написатели пакетных менеджеров.
